# Structure Linked List in C not connected well

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to make a linked list in C where every node has connections to both the right and the left. using insert_node function I have input 4 nodes with values : 2, 3, 5, 2

if I have writtenn the logic right, the insert node should have automatically sorted the list so that it is aligned as: 2,2,3,5

if I check the middle value in print_list, the value comes out as 3 which is what I had expected. However, as soon as I move to the left node using temporary node temp, temp becomes nullptr.

I don't see why that is happening because the temp node in print_list is initialized with the middle node of the list, and middle node is assigned a left node.

```
typedef struct ListNode{
    struct ListNode* right;
    struct ListNode* left;
    int value;
} ListNode;
//a linked list that saves the middle node of the list
typedef struct LinkedList{
    ListNode* middle;
    int left_size;
    int right_size;
}LinkedList;

//a function to reduce repeating malloc
ListNode* init_node() {
    return (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode*) * 2 + 4);
}
LinkedList* init_list() {
    return (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode*) + sizeof(int) * 2);
}


//function to assign NULL to unassigned pointers in structs 
void nullify_node(ListNode* node) {
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
}
void nullify_list(LinkedList* list) {
    list->middle = NULL;
}

//sorts the list so that the leftmost node has smallest value
void insert_node(LinkedList* list, int value) {

    ListNode* new_node = init_node();
    new_node->value = value;
    nullify_node(new_node);
    printf("initialized new node\n");
    
    //if no node was ever inserted in the list, make the new node be the middle one
    if (list->left_size+list->right_size==0) { 
        list->middle = new_node;
        list->right_size += 1;
    }
    else {
        //make a temporary node to traverse the list
        ListNode* temp =list->middle;
        nullify_node(temp);
        printf("initialized temp\n");
        
        //if given value is smaller or equal to that of the middle node, traverse to the left
        if (value <= list->middle->value) {
            int left_size = list->left_size;
            
            //if no node was ever inserted to the left, make the new node the first left node
            if (left_size == 0) {
                printf("initialized first left");
                list->middle->left=new_node;
                list->left_size += 1;
                
            }
            else {
                //temp->left should be the left node to new node
                //traverse temp until temp->left->value is smaller than value while temp->value is bigger than value
                for (; left_size > 0; left_size--) {
                    if (temp->left) {//only if temp->left exist check temp->left->value
                        //if temp->left->value is bigger than value, hop once more
                        if (value < temp->left->value) {
                            temp = temp->left;
                        }//if it is the same or bigger, stop there.
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //put new node between temp->left and temp
                if (temp->left) {
                    new_node->right = temp;
                    new_node->left = temp->left;
                    temp->left->right = new_node;
                    temp->left = new_node;
                }
                else {//if temp was the leftmost node, make new node be the leftmost node.
                    new_node->right = temp;
                    temp->left = new_node;
                }
                    

                //balance list
                list->left_size += 1;
                if (list->left_size > list->right_size + 1) {
                    list->middle = list->middle->left;
                    list->left_size -= 1;
                    list->right_size += 1;
                }
                        
                
            }
        }//traverse to the right side of the list if given value is bigger than the middle node's value
        else if (value > list->middle->value) {
            int right_size = list->right_size;
            //since middle value is considered as one of the right side's nodes, hop minus 1 time than the right_size
            for (; right_size > 1; right_size--) {
                if (temp->right) {// if temp has a right node, compare temp->right->value with given value
                    //if given value is bigger, move temp to the right
                    if (value > temp->right->value) {
                        temp = temp->right;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }               
            }
            //if temp wasn't the rightmost node,
            if (temp->right) {
                //insert new node between temp and temp->right
                new_node->left = temp;
                new_node->right = temp->right;
                temp->right->left = new_node;
                temp->right = new_node;
            }
            else {//if temp was the rightmost node, make the new node be the rightmost node
                temp->right = new_node;
                new_node->left = temp;
            }
            //balance list
            list->right_size += 1;
            if (list->right_size > list->left_size + 1) {
                list->middle = list->middle->right;
                list->left_size += 1;
                list->right_size -= 1;
            }
        }
            
    }
}
void print_list(LinkedList*list) {
    //move to leftmost node
    ListNode*temp = list->middle;
    printf("middlevalue:%d", temp->value);
    for (int i = 0; i < list->left_size ; i++) {
        //when input 2, 3, 5, 2, from the second interation temp is nullptr for some reason
        temp = temp->left;
        printf("%dth value:%d",i, temp->value);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < list->left_size + list->right_size; j++) {
        printf("\t%d", temp->value);
        temp = temp->right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `init_node` and `init_list` assume hard structure packing, and are just plain wrong. Those should look like this (lack of error checking notwithstanding):

```
ListNode *init_node(int value) // note argument
{
    ListNode * p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->left = p->right = NULL;
    p->value = value;
    return p;
}

LinkedList *init_list()
{
    LinkedList *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->left_size = p->right_size = 0;
    p->middle = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

Note the added argument to `init_node`. This allows this:

```
ListNode* new_node = init_node();
new_node->value = value;
nullify_node(new_node);
```

to become this:

```
ListNode *new_node = init_node(value);
```

Next, you apparently are having difficulties understanding how pointers work. When you do this:

```
//make a temporary node to traverse the list
ListNode *temp = list->middle;
nullify_node(temp);
printf("initialized temp\n");
```

You're actually pointing `temp` to the *same node* that your `list->middle` points to, then nulling out that nodes' left and right pointers. I.e. you just leaked anything on the left or right into the ether. Worse, the size parameters (which you heavily rely on throughout your code) are left as-is, meaning they are now accounting for list particulates that don't exist anymore (because you orphan/leaked them with that nullify_node).

Delete this line:

```
nullify_node(temp);
```

and ideally, with the advent of our new `init_node` implementation, just delete the function. it's effectively worthless anyway.

Finally, `print_list`. the argument should be const, and shouldn't rely on the size members of the `LinkedList` structure *whatsoever*. I.e.

```
void print_list(const LinkedList *list)
{
    //move to leftmost node
    const ListNode *temp = list->middle;
    if (temp)
    {
        while (temp->left)
            temp = temp->left;
    }

    while (temp)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gosh thank you sooooo much!!! It was sufficient for me. I appreciate that you took the time for such explicit explanation! I hope you have a great year :DD